# Typecast string to integer

Tags: postgresql

I am importing data from a table which has raw feeds in Varchar, I need to import a column in varchar into a string column. I tried using the `<column_name>::integer` as well as `to_number(<column_name>,'9999999')` but I am getting errors, as there are a few empty fields, I need to retrieve them as empty or null into the new table.

Comment: Could you show us the error message? That would help

Comment: If the error is something like
`Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""` see the solution using the [intval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518258/typecast-string-to-integer-postgres#60485123) function

Answer (score 185):

Wild guess: If your value is an empty string, you can use NULLIF to replace it for a NULL:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(your_value, '')::int
```

Answer (score 71):

You can even go one further and restrict on this coalesced field such as, for example:-

```
SELECT CAST(coalesce(<column>, '0') AS integer) as new_field
from <table>
where CAST(coalesce(<column>, '0') AS integer) >= 10;
```

Comment: why does coalesce need casting?

Comment: Coalesce itself does not need casting. It only ensures '0' (a string) is returned instead of `NULL`. It is the resulting value (which is a string) that needs casting to integer, per the original question.

Answer (score 35):

If you need to treat empty columns as `NULL`s, try this:

```
SELECT CAST(nullif(<column>, '') AS integer);
```

On the other hand, if you do have `NULL` values that you need to avoid, try:

```
SELECT CAST(coalesce(<column>, '0') AS integer);
```

I do agree, error message would help a lot.

Answer (score 30):

The only way I succeed to not having an error because of NULL, or special characters or empty string is by doing this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COALESCE(<column>::character varying, '0'), '[^0-9]*' ,'0')::integer FROM table
```

Comment: For me (9.6.2) this was the only thing that worked, all the other answers failed.

Comment: Couldn't you add a `WHERE <column> != NULL`?

Comment: Mathieu: adding WHERE column will exclude lines with NULL values in that column and maybe you want the NULL column to be converted to 0

Answer (score 16):

I'm not able to comment (too little reputation? I'm pretty new) on Lukas' post.

On my PG setup `to_number(NULL)` does not work, so my solution would be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column = NULL THEN NULL ELSE column :: Integer END
FROM table
```

Comment: This should work, but it should be an exact equivalent of the less verbose `NULLIF()` approach. The standard actually defines NULLIF as a form of the CASE predicate.

Answer (score 16):

If the value contains non-numeric characters, you can convert the value to an integer as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <column>~E'^\\d+$' THEN CAST (<column> AS INTEGER) ELSE 0 END FROM table;
```

The CASE operator checks the < column>, if it matches the integer pattern, it converts the rate into an integer, otherwise it returns 0

Answer (score 9):

### Common issue

Naively type casting any string into an integer like so

```sql
SELECT ''::integer
```

Often results to the famous error:

```
Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

## Problem

PostgreSQL has no pre-defined function for **safely** type casting any string into an integer.

### Solution

Create a user-defined function inspired by PHP's [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION intval(character varying) RETURNS integer AS $$

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN length(btrim(regexp_replace($1, '[^0-9]', '','g')))>0 THEN btrim(regexp_replace($1, '[^0-9]', '','g'))::integer
    ELSE 0
END AS intval;

$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

#### Usage

```sql
/* Example 1 */
SELECT intval('9000');
-- output: 9000

/* Example 2 */
SELECT intval('9gag');
-- output: 9

/* Example 3 */
SELECT intval('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
-- output: 0
```

Comment: Would fail for very large numbers. It'd work perfectly if you catch exceptions as well

Comment: @jaisonDavis the topic is about integer that's why it is expected that this solution would fail for very large numbers. You might want to consider creating a similar function to this solution eg: `bigintval()` and for that function replace anything that says `integer` and replace it with `bigint`. The fail is probably just about the [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html) limits.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this query

```
SUM(NULLIF(conversion_units, '')::numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect solution for me is to use `nullif` and `regexp_replace`

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE('98123162t3712t37', '[^0-9]', '', 'g'), '')::bigint;
```

Above solution consider the following edge cases.

1. String and Number: only the `regexp_replace` function perfectly converts into integers.

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE('string and 12345', '[^0-9]', '', 'g'), '')::bigint;
```

2. Only string: `regexp_replace` converts non-string characters to empty strings; which can't cast directly to integer so use `nullif` to convert to null

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE('only string', '[^0-9]', '', 'g'), '')::bigint;
```

3. Integer range: Converting a string into integer may cause **out of range for type integer** error. So use `bigint` instead

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE('98123162t3712t37', '[^0-9]', '', 'g'), '')::bigint;
```

Answer (score 0):

And if your column has decimal points

```
select NULLIF('105.0', '')::decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```sql
select (left(regexp_replace(coalesce('<column_name>', '0') || '', '[^0-9]', '', 'g'), 8) || '0')::integer
```

For easy view:

```sql
select (
    left(
        regexp_replace(
            -- if null then '0', and convert to string for regexp
            coalesce('<column_name>', '0') || '',
            '[^0-9]',
            '',
            'g'
        ),      -- remove everything except numbers
        8       -- ensure ::integer doesn't overload
    ) || '0'    -- ensure not empty string gets to ::integer
)::integer
```