# PostgreSQL : to_number() function

Tags: postgresql, casting

I need to cast a CHARACTER VARYING column into a NUMERIC type. The source column contains values like : 9.9 ; 99.9 ; NULL. I use the following SQL instruction :

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN pression TYPE NUMERIC USING to_number(pression, '99.9') ;
```

I get an error : « invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" » (SQL : 22P02)...

Is there a problem with having both 9.9 and 99.9 kinds of values ?

Thomas

Comment: In fact, it seems that I have empty cells in my column... I have found a solution by updating the column and giving any NULL cells a default value. Then, the casting is possible to NUMERIC. I finally have to update my column again to set the NULL value instead of the default...

Comment: see this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518258/typecast-string-to-integer-postgres

Comment: Thanks for the link I had read before posting. In my case, I do not use a SELECT but an ALTER TABLE so I can't use CAST() for exemple...

Comment: You can use any expression in the `USING` clause, including `cast`, `nullif()` and `to_number()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to cast a `null` to `numeric`:

```
select null::numeric;
 numeric 
---------

(1 row)

select to_number(null, '99.9');
 to_number 
-----------

(1 row)
```

But not an empty string:

```
select ''::numeric;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
LINE 1: select ''::numeric;
```

So update the column to null **before** altering it

```
update test
set pression = null
where pression = '';
```

Then alter it

```
ALTER TABLE test 
ALTER COLUMN pression TYPE NUMERIC USING to_number(pression, '99.9') ;
```

Comment: That's it ! The problem comes from cells containing ''. By updating them to NULL value, the casting works well. Thank you for this is probably the simpliest solution !