# how to i typecast string to integer - Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter

This query, return this error.

> operator does not exist: text = integer LINE 2: from mas_book ) as
>   outp where outp.authors = 2 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name
>   and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

```
public function authors($ids)
{
  $query = "select count(authors) from (select distinct regexp_split_to_table(author, E',') as authors
        from mas_book ) as outp where outp.authors = ".$ids;
        $result =   $this->db->query($query);
     return $result->result();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If outp.authors value can be converted into Integer then You can use :

```
"select count(authors) from (select distinct regexp_split_to_table(author, E',') as authors
        from mas_book ) as outp where to_number(outp.authors,'9999999') = ".$ids;
```

If It is not work then [See this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518258/typecast-string-to-integer-postgres)

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT COUNT(authors) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT regexp_split_to_table(author, E',') as authors
            FROM mas_book ) as outp WHERE outp.authors = ".'cast(.'$ids'. as character varying);
```